# How to define a field in elasticsearch which is aggrigatable on kibana (ELK 5.0)

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I've defined a field as an ip in the template and checked it is defined as ip in the relevant indexes.
But when I open the fields in kibana it appears as non searchable and non aggregatable (so I can't use it in the visualizer).
I've reloaded the fields several times but it didn't change.
Any help will be appreciated.
In the index mapping: GET myindex/_mapping

```
"properties": {
    "src": {
        "type": "ip"
    }
}
```

In kibana I see the logs and I can search based on the src field.
The problem is just in the fields view and visualizer.

Comment: If you could show us your logstash conf? And are you having your ip type field empty? I mean without any data?

Answer (score 0):

this should work :)

```
"properties": {
    "src": {
        "type": "ip",
        "fields": {
            "raw": {
                "type": "keyword"
            }
        }
    }
}
```